# Why am I getting a "Unable to parse NSPredicate" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I built the following predicate to use MagicalRecord against a Core Data store.

```
//  format the date correctly
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd*"];  //  HH:mm
NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:currentlySelectedDate];

NSString *stringPredicate = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:
                             @"aPosX >= %f AND aPosX < %f AND %f > aPosY AND %f <= (aPosY + aPosH) AND aStartTime LIKE %@",
                             [staffIndex floatValue], [staffIndex floatValue] + 218, touchPoint.y, touchPoint.y, formattedDate];

NSPredicate *predicate =  ([NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: stringPredicate]);
```

It crashes on the last statement, with this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "aPosX >= 218.000000 AND aPosX < 436.000000 AND 15.000000 > aPosY AND 15.000000 <= (aPosY + aPosH) AND aStartTime LIKE 2013-05-09*"'

I have tried everything I know of, searched Google and SO, and still don't understand why it's failing... can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a format string, use the predicate format creation method:

```
predicateWithFormat:
```

This allows the predicate to process the format parameters as it sees fit (adding quotes where required).

For the date, you need to modify the predicate to use a range. You can't directly check only the day of the date and ignore the time so you need to say:

```
date > startOfDay AND date < endOfDay
```

Where `startOfDay` and `endOfDay` are NSDate instances (probably created using `NSDateComponents`).

Comment: Thank you... it's not crashing anymore, but the predicate isn't working the way I expected it to... I have a date time stored in **astartTime** and it appears it's looking at the entire date/time.  I want only the **date**, not the time... How do I get it to do that?